# How is the SubscriberPackageVersionId dependency of *installed* package not found in my org's list of installed packages?

Tags: salesforcedx, package-install

Short:
Another way to phrase this question: *How to query against a `SubscriberPackageVersionId` to discover if it is the latest version of said package*

TL;DR;
I've created a Powershell script that prompts me for 2 aliases (orgs that I have previously authorized), let's call them 'source' and 'target' orgs.

It then proceeds to execute a CLI command for each alias provided:
`sfdx force:package:installed:list -u <<alias>>`

It then does a diff between the two lists of installed packages and proceeds to install any missing packages on the 'target'

[image]

Now, because the default list output from the above command is in no particular order (re: dependencies) I sometimes have to execute the script a 2nd time before everything is leveled up

I noticed if I step through the list output, and use the SubscriberPackageVersionId (04t..) to look up dependencies..

`sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT Dependencies FROM SubscriberPackageVersion WHERE Id='$pkgAlias'"`

...I would expect any reported dependencies to be discoverable somewhere in my initial query that I explained above. However, I'm finding that is not always the case.

I have seen this [simple script from Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_install_pkg_sample_script.htm) that just issues installation commands directly against the reported dependencies.. but I am assuming this may be installation overkill... since my script will then proceed to install a newer version of the dependency that it wasn't smart enough to put in the right order.

To reiterate: I think the mis-match may be that that Package A may be reporting a dependency on an older version of Package B thus I don't have the clues I need within my initial query to properly order my set of SubscriberPackageVersion numbers.

Anybody have any bright ideas?